# A Java Servlet problem where I have a Null Parameter from the HTTPRequest object, how do I send the parameter using URL Queries?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I decided to send a request to a Java Servlet by using webpage links that send URL requests to the Java Servlet.

So, in my  attribute I have something like the following:

```
<%
 for(int i = 0; i<companies.length; i++)
 {
  String link = "InactiveEmployees?company="+companies[i].getName()+" ";
%>
<p><a href="<%= link %>" type="_top">
<% companies[i].getName(); %>
</a></p>
<br />
<%
 }
%>
```

Yet, when I look at the Glassfish server log (server.log), I see that I have a NULLRefereneException which occurs in the Java Servlet that I wrote to handle the request.  With some tweaking, I found out that I was sending a blank request.  The parameter titled "company" is sent NULL every time.

Is there a reason why this should be happening?  If I'm not mistaken, when you want to send a request parameter to a server for the particular document, you do have something like the following:

```
protocol://domain_name.top_level_domain_name/directory/document?parameters=value
```

am I correct?

If there's any insight that an experienced web programmer can give me, that would be great.  Thanks in advanced!

Comment: We really need to see more code to help you debug this. Are you sure companies[i].getName() is not returning null?

Comment: Your problem lies somewhere else. An empty parameter is by default not retrieved as `null`. Please look at the stacktrace once again, trackback the first line of the stacktrace to the actual code and then update your question to include exactly this line (and the minimum necessary lines *before* this line which shows how all the variables are been obtained/gathered).

Comment: Is your for loop executing to create each link, i.e. `companies` itself is not null? Do you also see the word NULL on the screen if print it out in JSP `companies[i].getName(); ` as well. Though that should be `<%= companies[i].getName(); %>`. you missed the `=`

Comment: No, I didn't  If you'll notice, the second Java tag isn't a value that would be put into an HTTP command parameter.  It's the actual text that would appear where the link is.  So, I don't see why I would need an equal sign there.

Comment: Liars: the `<%= %>` prints the method return value. The `<% %>` does nothing with return values. As to the concrete problem, it's still unclear where the NPE originate. Work on that first.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the <%= link %> missed out the protocol of

> protocol://domain_name.top_level_domain_name